# Kinect on PC/Windows 7 (OpenNI - "device missing", but Kinect SDK samples DO works)

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk, openni

I Have an Kinect (the bit old one, for xbox 360) and an PC (windows 7 x64).

I've downloaded the Kinect SDK from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561

I've made an restart, plugged in the Kinect to power and PC/usb. Device Manager looks ok:
[image]

I want to run the Unity demo for Kinect (then write my own one): https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10693

As far as I know the  http://www.openni.org/ is down, so I've downloaded and installed the OpenNI from http://structure.io/openni (`OpenNI 2.2.0.33 Beta (x64)`).

But when I run the Unity demo, Kinect does not react to my movements at all.

All the demos from `C:\Program Files\OpenNI2\Samples\Bin` **fails as well**:

[image]

On the other hand, the demos from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.0 Beta2\Samples\bin` (Kinect SDK) **works perfectly** (showing the camera image, `SkeletalViewer` interprets my posture as skeleton etc.):
[image]

The LED on the Kinect blinks periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid OpenNI is a dead project, probably Kinect drivers changed in meantime and they are no more compatible.

You should definitely switch to a more mantained framework, such as [OpenKinect](https://github.com/OpenKinect)

Comment: It is dead (I've mention it in my question), but it has many copies like http://structure.io/openni And I need it to work with Unity, I guess (almost any Unity tutorial about Kinect, including the new ones, point me to get the OpenNI): http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Microsoft_Kinect_-_Open_NI Unfortunatelly, I've not found an info how OpenKinect can be integrated with Unity (if it's possible).

Comment: Looks like there are no wrappers for Unity and openkinect.
Can I ask you what is stopping you from using official drivers?

Comment: What you mean by "using official drivers"? I have installed Kinect SDK from MS website but it's not enough to work with Kinect on Unity. I DO have to install the OpenNI etc. (every single tutorial point it out). I am not aware about any other "official driver" that would allow me to work with Kinect on Unity. I may be wrong, I'm the very beginner in the "field of Kinect."

Comment: You do not have to use OpenNI to have Kinect Support in Unity. Newer version of sdk have got a binding inside. Check the [microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn782041.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: That's pretty exiting. Sad thing is it's only for Unity Pro (as I see on microsoft documentation) and I use just Unity.